# consulta (algebra relacional) extracción de de datos

Tags: base-de-datos, filtro, álgebra-relacional

Quiero hacer el código de algebra lineal para poder filtrara una base de datos, de ese modo hallar los sueldos que poseen mayor sueldo que el que me piden.

Este es mi codigo:

```
r1=πsueldo(σd_nombre='Miguel Sapochnik' ∧ e_nombre='Hardhome'(Dirige))
r2=πd_nombre,e_nombre(σ sueldo > r1.sueldo (Dirige))
r2
```

lo estoy haciendo en relaX, pero no me corre
¿Cuál es el error?
Por favor si me repsonden me pueden decir porque da error

Comment: Mucho gusto con [RelaX](https://dbis-uibk.github.io/relax/landing). ¿Da algún error en particular? Pulsa en [edit] para especificarlo. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: @padaleiana me sale el siguiente error "Error: no se pude encontrar columna "r1" en esquema [Dirige.d_nombre : string, Dirige.e_nombre : string, Dirige.s_nombre : string, Dirige.sueldo : number]"   no se que debreía hacer

Comment: Pon esa aclaración en la pregunta misma. Los comentarios son efímeros.